# Create Spinner Programmatically

Tags: android

I have to create a Spinner which is not in my Layout.

so I want to create it Programmatic I write the following code in My Activity class

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
String option[]={"By Date","By Transaction ID","By Customer Phone"};
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,option);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
spinner.performClick();
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View v,int position, long id)
    {
        Log.d("in select","yes");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("In No select","No");
    }
});
```

**so My question is how I can access the spinner selected item in the activity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View v,int position, long id)
{
    Log.d("in select","yes");
}
```

The `position` helps you to retrieve your selected item. Which, in your case, it should be:

```
option[position]
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but onItemSelected function is not called, so how i retrieve value without calling it, why it is not calling

Comment: Yeah just put your backing array in the activity and use the positon to figure out which thing was selected.

Comment: my array is already in activity, i see the spinner view very fine, but when i select any item then nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Your only way to access it outside your listener is making a variable that will hold the position, so you would use it later.
Something like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private int curPos;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    String option[]={"By Date","By Transaction ID","By Customer Phone"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,option);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinner.performClick();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View v,int position, long id)
        {
            curPos = position;
            Log.d("in select","yes");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("In No select","No");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hey, i think you not understand correctly, my problem is that the execution is not reach the onItemSelected block

Comment: Oh, sorry.
Did you try to debug it and put a break point in the opening of the "onItemSelected" method?